# WebBrowser component not showing CSS 3

Tags: c#, css, webbrowser-control

I am building a piece of software that requires a WebBrowser component.
Unfortunately it won't show my page correctly.

My content uses this CSS style:

```
.content_mid{
background-image:url(http://img.awesome-o.net/Content_Mid.png);
background-size: 100% 100%;
vertical-align:text-top;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right:20px;
min-height:400px; 
}
```

Since I already found out the WebBrowser component uses the installed version of interwebs explorer, I checked the html on Internet Explorer, and it shows perfectly.

Here you see what it shows on IE:

[image]

And here is how it displays on the webbrowser component:

[image]

So, I checked the browser version:

```
Debug.WriteLine("WebBrowser version: " + webBrowser1.Version);
output: WebBrowser version: 9.0.8112.16443
```

So that should be alright I guess.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for further reference to other people needing this:

First of all:
Thanks to [Boo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74015/boo) & [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li)
For helping me find the answer to my question.

You have to set a certain registry to the right value:

> There are two different sets of keys for 32 bit and 64 bit applications.

32 bit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Value Key: yourapplication.exe
```

64 bit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Value Key: yourapplication.exe
```

The value to set this key to is (taken from MSDN here) as decimal values:

```
9999 (0x270F)
Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the  !DOCTYPE directive.

 9000 (0x2328)
 Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.

8888 (0x22B8)
Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

8000 (0x1F40)
Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode.

7000 (0x1B58)
Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode.
```

Even tough MSDn claims that 9000 is the automatically assigned value. Apperently this is simply not true.

Below you can find the code how to add these keys to your registry. Please not that your application has a different processname when you debug.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
        if (key != null)
        {
            key.SetValue("YourApplicationName.exe", 9000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }

        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
        if (key != null)
        {
            key.SetValue("YourApplicationName.exe", 9000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
```

So thanks all and Good Luck

Edit: User Account Control should be off to make this code work.

Answer (score 23):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes how to force the browser control to use a specific render mode.

You can also try this *doctype*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And/Or this meta element in the head element:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, just one thing i dont get.
"The default value for Internet Explorer 9 is 9000."
"Description:  Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode."

That seems the right value for me, or do you think differently?

Comment: Does your page define a doctype ?

Comment: Yes it does:

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Sorry i tried them out vyt they dont seem to work, thanks for the answers tough.

Comment: There is a nice blog post containing more details, http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Comment: Thank you both!! manually setting the variable to 9000 made this work!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I changed this line:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

to

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

to the latest verison of IE and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add a response header to the IIS application Called X-UA-Compatible with a value of IE=Edge. I tend to add it to my web.config

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm afraid this is concernign a windows forms application. There is no web.config.